# QGIS GUI layout and screen scaling in Windows

Tags: qgis, resolution, display, gui

I am using the QGIS 3.30 GUI and the interface size doesn't seem to scale to my display/screen display and the bottom bar (where you have a box to display the map scale) is misaligned.

Is there a simple fix to correct the layout?

Before the upgrade, I had to leave full-screen mode as well in the previous version to see the bottom progress bar when running a heavy process.

Yesterday, I tried changing the built-in options for font and icon size, but this only solves my problem partly and makes the whole GUI rather unworkable (with either too small text or blurred icons). I am running QGIS on a 13” Laptop with a full HD 1080 screen.

- First image: the GUI with the mScaleWidget enabled
- Second image: mScaleWidget disabled

[[image: Screenshot of the GUI1]

[image: Status bar with mScaleWidget disabled]

Comment: You only have this problem with QGIS, not with other software? Can you post a screenshot? Are you sure your QGIS window is maximized?

Comment: From the discussion in the first answer, it seems that disabling the mScaleWidget will make the Status bar readable, but this is not ideal. 

Follow-up question: is it possible to reorder the elements on the Status bar, as the main problem is the scaling of the screen (which has to be 150% on my system) and how QGIS is working with px/in on screen in Qt interfaces?

Comment: Not sure about that. Maybe post this as a separate question

Comment: Some related conversation on gitHub: https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/40274

Comment: By the way: your question made me realize that my scale field in status bar is too small: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSQP4.png Seems to be a general problem...

Comment: Since you are using Windows, does changing the High DPI settings (right click icon in taskbar > Properties > Compatibility> Change high DPI settings) make any difference perhaps? Just spitballing here...

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @she_weeds, I have set the High DPI settings to override the scaling with the enhanced system setting, and that helps, but I can't manage to have the full status bar; I need to deactivate the mScaleWidget to have a readable bar.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you have somehow deactivated status bar. To activate it, go to Menu <kbd>Seetings</kbd> > <kbd>Interface Customization...</kbd> and check the box next to <kbd>Enable customization</kbd>. Then go to <kbd>StatusBar</kbd> an check the box next to it (see screenshot). Close and restart QGIS and the Status Bar should be visible again.

[image]

Also try Menu <kbd>Settings</kbd> > <kbd>Options</kbd> > <kbd>General</kbd> tab and change style and UI theme:

[image]

Comment: I added the screenshot; the problem is with the scaling of the screen. I can't set the screen scale to 100% because of the size and resolution of my display. In 3.26 I didn't have this problem, but upgrading to 3.30 made the GUI less user-friendly (somehow).

Comment: Did you try deactivating and reactivating status bar?

Comment: Yes, dis/enabling status bar doesn't fix the object sizes on the status bar, as you can see in my screenshot, the map scale dropdown box is too large in relation to the other elements.

Comment: Try to deactivate `mScaleWidget` in the Interface Customization and restart QGIS. The map scale box should disappear. Reactive it and restart QGIS.

Comment: If I disable mScaleWidget the status bar is very readable, when I enable the Widget the placement is making all the other elements on the bar not readable anymore - unfortunately I can post a screenshot (I think)

Comment: See updated answer. Post your screenshot by editing the initial question

Comment: I tried your suggestion, and my settings there are: 
- icon size 24
- font size 10
I can change to icon 16 (too small) and 8 but then I get other problems, there are some fonts which are not affected by this change.

Comment: Hm, difficult to say. Maybe the settings are hidden somewhere in the Settings > Options > Advanced tab

Comment: Thanks, @Babel, for your help and suggestions; perhaps I can send a question to the developers - it's a little annoying not having the scale in the status bar.

Comment: Please report back if you solve the problem