# Reducing size of panels inside QGIS UI

Tags: qgis, gui, icon, size

I would like to reduce the size of panels in QGIS. I can easily reduce front and icon size by going to settings>general>font/icon size. But this doesn't change the size of the panels.

It's better explained by a picture: I've reduced the icon and font size in the toolbars to a nice size, but as an example, the layer style panel remains unaffected. I would like this to be much more compressed so it displays more of the panel without me having to expand it.

[image: panel size too big]

Comment: Hi Jasper, if you feel your question has been solved don't forget to mark the answer as 'accepted' to help others more easily find the solution in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Your question relates to a problem I have, but I might know how to solve your scaling issue, as it involves the whole GUI. Link to my question: [QGIS GUI layout and screen scaling in Windows](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/457210/qgis-gui-layout-and-screen-scaling-in-windows)

Have you tried to:

- set your OS screen scale to 100% (this is where the problem comes from).
- if this is not possible (to the high resolution of the display), then you could try to tweak the compatibility of the GUI by setting the DPI scaling (see screenshot)

[image: DPI scaling]

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Gijs van den Dool. I managed to achieve the results by changing the font style as well as the size and this successfully scaled the panels correctly. Thank you.